# MySQL Select syntax gives me two rows per id output what's is wrong?

Tags: mysql, select, phpmyadmin

**table structure:**
[image]

```
SELECT p.id id, p.type
    TYPE , v.provider provider, v.video_id video_id, NULL content, NULL url, NULL posted_by
    FROM post p
    INNER JOIN p_video v ON p.id = v.id
    AND p.type =  'video'
    UNION 
    SELECT p.id, p.type, NULL , NULL , t.content, NULL , NULL 
    FROM post p
    INNER JOIN p_text t ON p.id = t.id
    AND p.type =  'text'
    UNION 
    SELECT p.id, p.type, NULL , NULL , NULL , i.url, NULL 
    FROM post p
    INNER JOIN p_image i ON p.id = i.id
    AND p.type =  'image'
    UNION 
    SELECT p.id, p.type, NULL , NULL , NULL , l.url, NULL 
    FROM post p
    INNER JOIN p_link l ON p.id = l.id
    AND p.type =  'link'
    UNION 
    SELECT p.id, NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL , u.name
    FROM post p
    LEFT JOIN user u ON p.user_id = u.id
    ORDER BY id DESC 
    LIMIT 0 , 30
```

[image: mySQL output]

What's my syntax error? It just makes 2 rows.. but I want all the output in seperate 1 rows.

Comment: This definitely looks like a weird approach.  The `UNION`s are responsible for the duplicate row. Post your table structure please, and we can help.

Comment: I can't explain this behaviour. I postet a bit of the main table. The other tables are like in SQL statement.

Comment: When we ask to post a table structure, please post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, not a picture of your screen with the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT p.id id, p.type
TYPE , v.provider provider, v.video_id video_id, NULL content, NULL url, u.name posted_by
FROM post p
LEFT JOIN user u ON p.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN p_video v ON p.id = v.id
AND p.type =  'video'
UNION 
SELECT p.id, p.type, NULL , NULL , t.content, NULL , u.name
FROM post p
LEFT JOIN user u ON p.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN p_text t ON p.id = t.id
AND p.type =  'text'
UNION 
SELECT p.id, p.type, NULL , NULL , NULL , i.url, u.name
FROM post p
LEFT JOIN user u ON p.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN p_image i ON p.id = i.id
AND p.type =  'image'
UNION 
SELECT p.id, p.type, NULL , NULL , NULL , l.url, u.name
FROM post p
LEFT JOIN user u ON p.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN p_link l ON p.id = l.id
AND p.type =  'link'
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 0):

It's your last union select, which adds the second row. If you want to have it with each row add the left join to every union select part and leave out the last union select

```
SELECT p.id id, p.type
TYPE , v.provider provider, v.video_id video_id, NULL content, NULL url, u.name posted_by
FROM post p
INNER JOIN p_video v ON p.id = v.id
AND p.type =  'video'
LEFT JOIN user u ON p.user_id = u.id
UNION 
SELECT ...
...
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```